# What is more efficient one function with an if statement or two functions? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, performance

So I created this jsperf test which leaves me still clueless

http://jsperf.com/testing-extra-function-vs-if-statement

Basically I have two different searches and items that are able to be created, now I can have option 1:

2 functions:

`export.create_item_1 ...` and `export.create_item_2...` to be called from the clientside which is more code on the serverside but less thinking...

or option 2 is to have less code but more thinking/nesting:

```
export.create_item () {
 var item = req.query.item;
   if(item == 1) {
    method1();
   }

   if(item == 2) {
    method2();
   }
}
```

Not sure which one is more efficient for the server side... is more code but less thinking/nesting or less code with an if statement... I am assuming option 1

Comment: you tell us? Write it both ways, run each 100000 times on randomised input, see which is faster.

Comment: How would I go about testing it, I wrote the jsperf is there a way to improve the test on jsperf? I do not have a server and what not ready to run a large amount of tests like that

Comment: just write the code as standalone code in a test.js file, then run that with `node test.js`?

Comment: there are too many things involved for it to be standalone code to give me a true result... because the client is an android app currently sending info to the server grabbing it from the db so it will just end up being like the jsperf results

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't worry about optimizations like this unless you have determined that it is a major bottleneck in your application. More likely than not, other things will be your bottleneck before issues like this.

Either way, running the jsperf in Chrome (or viewing the Chrome results from others) is all you should really need to do to answer your question.

Comment: Well the thing is I either write a whole separate route file with 4 new functions or just have 4 if statements in the current file and switch it based off the item number and I rather the server fire off results than have to constantly check is this 1 or 2... but if it is not an optimization game changer then ok I might just do option 1 then

Comment: Definitely a pre-mature optimization.